# PCA in Matlab - Are the Principal Compoents re-arranged?

Tags: pca, matlab

I am trying to do a PCA on some volatility data, and let's just say I can propose a model as the following:

```
volatility = bata0 + beta1*x + beta2* x^2
```

where x are some observations, say for example, moneyness and so on. 
So in Matlab, what I did was to say `Y=[ones x x^2]` and then do `pca(Y)`
and for some reason, my first row in my coefficient matrix is always something like 0 0 1, i.e., 0 everywhere else except the last column, and output of atent always shows the highest value in the first row as well, no matter how I change the model.

Obviously, this can't be the case where the last term in every single model is explained well by the last term in the equation. And if I remove the constant term in Y (i.e., Y= [x x^2] then the first row of coefficient matrix becomes something more normal (i.e., non-zero value everywhere).

So my questions are:

1. is my way of doing PCA right?
2. Does PCA automatically rearrange the principal component and hence the first row in the coefficient matrix with all zeros except 1 at the last column may not necessarily represent the last term in the equation and
3. if it is wrong, what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: This isn't a quant finance question. I'm sending it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

From Matlab's documentation for princomp:

> COEFF = princomp(X) performs principal components analysis (PCA) on
>   the n-by-p data matrix X, and returns the principal component
>   coefficients, also known as loadings. Rows of X correspond to
>   observations, columns to variables. COEFF is a p-by-p matrix, each
>   column containing coefficients for one principal component. **The
>   columns are in order of decreasing component variance.**

Comment: thanks @michaelv2, is there any way to prevent this re-arrangement or at least labelling clearly in the way they are re-arranged?